# The contentSize of the tableView is incorrect after I setting the height of footer

Tags: ios, footer

I set the height of footer in section  here.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSDictionary *dic = _dataArr[section];
return [YhtCellAdapter adapterHeightOfFooter:[dic[@"type"] integerValue]];}
```

[image: Here is the picture.(there is a space in the bottom)]

1: If I set the height to `0.01f`, the space will disappear. Why is the `contentSize` of the tableView incorrect after I set the height?

2: If I change the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` to `UITableViewStylePlain`, the space is gone. But the footer will float in the bottom, and I have no idea how to hide the footer.

Comment: How do you know the `contentSize` is at fault? Have you examined its value?

Comment: Of course,I do. If I do not set the height of footer, there is no space in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Tableview.layoutIfNeeded()` after setting The height of The footer.